# Correct request type for this context?

Tags: laravel

I have this route, after the user creates an account is generated a random token that is stored in the users table and the user receives an email with a link to this route to confirm the account. Its working but I dont know if it should be a get request or post request. Because in the `index()` the token field of the users table is updated, and the GET request is to request data from the server and POST to send data to the server. Do you know which route is more appropriate?

```
Route::get('/register/confirm', 'ConfirmEmailController@index');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need GET here since you want the user to be able to access it via a link in an email. You won't be able to generate a POST from an email link.